# Get only first character with specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014.  I have some string values i.e.:

```
A BCD
QWE
B YUI
ZZZZ
N POU
```

However, I'm only interested if the string is a single character and between a-z.  So from the above, I would want:

```
A
B
N
```

I know I can use `LIKE '[A-Z]%` but I only want there the length is 1 char - how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT LEFT(column_name, 1)
FROM table_name 
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(column_name, 2))) LIKE '[A-Z]'
```

... or a solution using [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql):

```
SELECT LEFT(column_name, 1) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE PATINDEX('[A-Z][^A-Z]%', column_name) > 0 OR PATINDEX('[A-Z]', column_name) > 0
```

... or a solution using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT LEFT(column_name, 1) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name LIKE '[A-Z][^A-Z]%' OR column_name LIKE '[A-Z]'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d66b9fcf1537ab5a9209fb6481a2cdab)

Answer (score 1):

Take the first 2 chars of the column and right trim it.
If the result is a single char `A-Z` then return it:

```
select left(col, 1) result
from tablename
where rtrim(left(col, 2)) like '[A-Z]'
```

Change `col` with the column's name.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3fb83af146d1e419e54778b8bbac7dc5).
Results:

```
> | result |
> | :----- |
> | A      |
> | B      |
> | N      |
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c28cc7/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
    ([col] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO tablename
    ([col])
VALUES
    ('A BCD'),
    ('QWE'),
    ('B YUI'),
    ('ZZZZ'),
    ('N POU')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select left(col, 1) result
from tablename
WHERE charindex(' ', col, 2)<>0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c28cc7/2/0)**:

```
| result |
|--------|
|      A |
|      B |
|      N |
```